# How to adopt FormRequest to API JSON request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to adopt FormRequest to API JSON request? Now it looks as:

```
class CreateOrder extends FormRequest
{

 // Validation rules

   public function rules()
{
    return [
        'DeliveryDate' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y H:m:s',
        'PostCard' => 'boolean',
        'PostCardText' => 'string|max:250',
        'PhotoBefore' => 'boolean',
        'Remark' => 'string|max:200',
        'OrderDate' => 'required|date_format:d-m-Y',
        'CallRecipientBefore' => 'boolean',
        'AnonymousDelivery' => 'boolean',
        'PhotoAfter' => 'boolean',
        'Employers_Id' => 'required|integer',
        'Employers_Id' => 'required|integer',
        'Partners_Id' => 'required|integer',
    ];
}

   public function authorize()
   {
       return true;
   }

}
```

And using:

```
public function store(CreateOrder $request)
{

 dd(Request::get('DeliveryDate'));
 dd($request->all()); // Or
}
```

When I send data to this endpoint, Laravel instead showing incoming data `$request`, does redirect.

**Sending data**
Using Postman data is sent in raw format as:

```
{
"DeliveryDate": "2018-01-01"
}
```

As result I give Laravel screen saver.

So, I have did some tests, method is not called at all:

```
 public function store(CreateOrder $request)
    {

        dd('ss');
    }
```

Seems an error in class: `CreateOrder`

Comment: Elaborate more. It isn't very clear what you are asking or what is the issue.

Comment: Be default `FormRequest` works with HTML forms, and POST method. But I try to send POST as JSON format. So `FormRequest` does not work in this case

Comment: Yes, it does. I work exclusively doing APIs and use Form Request without any problems. Add the related items: your API call (headers/body), route, request & controller method to see where the problem lays off.

Comment: Okay, now I will extend question

Comment: Where are you redirect to? What does it return?

Comment: I assume, that redirect works, but I can not catch this moment, I think Laravel does not aware about JSON incoming format and does redirect somewhere upper

Comment: I'm sure the problem is with how are you doing your call. Try adding the header: `Accept: application/json` (note, this is different that the `Content-type: application/json`)

Comment: Possible, let me check please

Comment: The same issues, it returns Laravel screen saver

Comment: Please, make a complete question. Add the errors, the full api call, and all the neccesary related code to know where the issue is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184057/discussion-between-opv-and-hck).

Comment: So, I tried to add corresponding message for each  rule, the same situation

Comment: I have found problem, if validation is fail, it redeirects before calling controller

Comment: To solve this I have to overwrire `redirect method` of parent class `class FormRequest extends Request implements ValidatesWhenResolved {}`